# override Jenkis/Hudson BUILD_URL

Tags: jenkins, hudson

Is it possible to override or change build url?

I've tried to set $BUILD_URL as pre step but it doesn't seem to be working.

Default Build URL : `host:8080/job/H_tests_tests/13/`

I want to have something like `host:8080/job/H_tests_tests/REV2315_13`

where `REV2315 = REV_${SVN_REVISION}` and `13` is the jenkins build number.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Might be advisable to include a bit more information / code.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot overwrite jenkins/hudson environment variables. It may be possible to temporary overwrite them in a build step, but it will be lost once you get to other build steps or to post-build steps.

- You can investigate EnvInject plugin
  https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin
- However an easier approach would be to create the URL you want from other components
  `${JOB_URL}/REV${SVN_REVISION}_${BUILD_NUMBER}` will get you what you asked for

Comment: I don't see `JOB_URL` here https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project

Answer (score 0):

Treat Jenkins' Environment-Variables as "*Read-Only*" and don't try to manipulate them.

The code should be able to run in different locations - 
it is best not to rely on the script running in a specific folder
because that folder can change, depending the Jenkins-configuration
(like when you change a Job to run on a *Slave* instead of on the *Master*,
or when you switch from one *Slave* to another).

Try to use paths that are *not relative* to Jenkins' working-folder,
as this location may change, for example:
The script can change-dir to a predefined location, do its work,
then copy the artifacts to another predefined location.