# How to detect and use updated values in config.xml

Tags: jenkins

I'm new to Jenkins and I want to do a build with a custom version. I created a job with parameters and I set two parameters:

- version (default value is 1.0.0)
- buildNumber (default value is 1)

When I build the job I input the version and build numbers and build the project. Jenkins passes the two properties to my ant script which builds the file. The last step of the build updates the `version` and `buildNumber` values in the Jenkins configuration file (`jenkins_home\jobs\jobName\config.xml`).

My question is that I find that the `config.xml` file has been updated as expected but when I build again it doesn't show the new values. It's like the values are being cached somehow. How can I make Jenkins show the new values?

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding what you're trying to do, but why does your build process update the jenkins build config.xml? Seems strange to me. What are you trying to accomplish ultimately?

Comment: my jar file name may like this: app_v1.0.1_beta1.jar.here 1.0.1 is version number,which is decided when build by custom input,not automatic increase,and beta1,the number after beta is the build number which increase by 1 every build,but when the version number changed,the build number reset to 1,so i need 2 input box to input these two numbers,i try to use parameter to input,that's why i need to update config.xml

Answer (score 3):

You should not try to manhandle the content of the *config.xml* file,
or the content of any Jenkins' environment variables.

Use plugins for that, like **[Next Build Number Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Next+Build+Number+Plugin)**
or **[Version Number Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Version+Number+Plugin)**.

See also here:
**[Override Jenkis/Hudson BUILD_URL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13996906/1390251)**

(Jenkins will not monitor any changes to it's job-configuration files,
unless you choose to reload the configuration, which is bad practice, in general).

Cheers